# AspNetCore 3.1 Web API serverless - how to manage lazy connection initialization

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-lambda

I am building AspNetCore 3.1 Web API serverless lambda application.

I have been advised that connections (for example: Redis connection) initialization shall be done outside of function handler. This is to make use of connection pooling in better way.

Azure team has also suggested the same:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-dotnet-core-quickstart

I am looking forward to see how we can achieve it when using Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer#bootstrapping-application-iwebhostbuilder-vs-ihostbuilder

Response or any other pointer to solve the issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So as an example of this.

```
namespace blankCsharp
{
  public class Function
  {
    private static RedisClient redisClient; <<

    static Function() {
      initialize();
    }

    static async void initialize() {
      AWSSDKHandler.RegisterXRayForAllServices();
      redisClient = new RedisClient('1.2.3.4', 6379, 'username', 'password'); << initialised and reusable between invocations.
      await callLambda();
    }

    public async Task<AccountUsage> FunctionHandler(SQSEvent invocationEvent, ILambdaContext context)
    {
      return redisClient.get('dhddhdhdud')
    }
  }
}
```

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve. By setting it in the initialize section it should be able to maintain the connection between invocations as long as it is not a cold start.

You should bare in mind that by default Lambda traverses the internet so your Redis K/V store will need to be hosted publicly.

If you want to run this privately you'd need to look at migrating your Lambda into a private subnet by [attaching it to a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html).

Comment: Thank you for the good example. I would appreciate if you have an example for how to make it work in AspNetCore Web API using APIGatewayProxyFunction